# Message lost while the receiver's presence is not updated in OF server

Tags: xmpp, chat, message, openfire

I have browsed this forum searching solution for this problem but couldnt find one. My issue is same as this,
https://vanity-igniterealtime.jiveon.com/message/225504
https://igniterealtime.org/issues/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/OF-161/OF-161.ht ml

I have configured the Ping request from server side for 30 seconds. But still 30 second is huge time. During that time lots of message are getting lost.

1. XEP-0184 is more of a client side delivery receipt management. Is that possible that i can get the acknowledgement in server as well?
2. Is it possible to store all the message in OF until we receive the delivery receipt from receiver. And delete the message from OF once we get the delivery receipt.

Please suggest me on how to prevent this message loss.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [XEP-0198](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html) which is unfortunately [not yet implemented for OpenFire](https://igniterealtime.org/issues/browse/OF-446).

Comment: Thanks legoscia. Is there any OF plugin available to handle this? Any clue about when Openfire will be updated with XEP-198.

Comment: [This blog post](https://www.atklique.com/bridge/blog/?q=node/5) mentions a plugin, but doesn't give any details.  [This forum post](https://vanity-igniterealtime.jiveon.com/message/210550#240112) says that there is a closed-source plugin, and that the author might be persuaded to contribute the code, but also doesn't go into details.  The JIRA issue linked above says "this feature won't be implemented soon without a help of the community", so there is no clear estimate on when this might happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there is no working solution in openfire 3.9.3 version.

What i have done is created a custom plugin,
* This will intercept the message packet and add it to custom table, until it receives ack packet from the receiver.

By this way we are avoiding the message loss.

Comment: Can you please share the Custom plugin you created for message loss I am also facing the same problem.